# Using 'system ("COLOR [attr]")' in C++

Tags: c++, colors

I am working on a code where I need to display my output in different colors according to the input given by user. 
How can I do this? 
To tried the following code to begin with, but it's not working.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{       
    system ( "TITLE Color Check" );
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
         system ( "COLOR i" );
         cout << "This color is COLOR" << i << endl;
    }


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [*curses*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)).

Comment: @Theolodis I realized this won't work that is why I asked how to display in various colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
for(int i = 31; i < 38; i++) 
    cout << "\e[0;" << i << "m"<< "This color is COLOR " << i << "\e[0;0m" << endl;
```

Just use the correct color codes:

- '\e[0;31m' # Red
- '\e[0;32m' # Green
- '\e[0;33m' # Yellow
- '\e[0;34m' # Blue
- '\e[0;35m' # Purple
- '\e[0;36m' # Cyan
- '\e[0;37m' # White